# How to check that java.lang.reflect.Method return type is Collection?

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I have method to get list of bean properities like below. How to check that method return type is collection (like List, Set...). isInstance(Collection.class) doesn't work.

```
public static List<String> getBeanProperties(String className, boolean withLists) {

    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList();
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(className);
        Method methods[] = c.getMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            String m = methods[i].getName();
            if(m.startsWith("get") && methods[i].getParameterTypes().length == 0) {

                if((methods[i].getReturnType().isInstance(Collection.class)) && !withLists) {
                    // skip lists
                } else {
                    String f = m.substring(3);
                    char ch = f.charAt(0);
                    char lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
                    f = lower + f.substring(1);
                    a.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)`. [Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Nice!. Thank You. You are very fast! :)

Comment: That's why we pay him the big bucks.

Answer (score 1):

`Method#getReturnType` returns a single Class object, the Class object that corresponds to the method declaration. If the method is declared to return a `Collection`, you'll see a collection. If it is declared to return a subclass of `Collection` (`List', ..), you'll need to check, if`Collection` is assignable from the actual return type:

```
 Class<?> realClass = methods[i].getReturnType(); // this is a real class / implementation
 if (Collection.isAssignableFrom(realClass)) {
    // skip collections (sic!)
 }
```